# Binding UpdateSource event

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I use editable label control (label with overrided template property; full code you see there: http://www.nathanpjones.com/wp/2012/09/editable-label-in-wpf/ ).

I create own label contol class with this style. EditableLabelControl class extends Label class, so EditableLabelControl has Content property.

```
public partial class EditableLabelControl : Label
{
    //...
}
```

After that I put this editable label in my custom control and bind it to model's **MyValue** property.

```
<controls:EditableLabelControl Content="{Binding Path=MyValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

It correctly displays model value, but when I made edits in textbox it updates Content property only (model's **MyValue** property doesn't updates).

I tryed to write LostFocus handler for textbox, but it doesn't help.

```
var bindingExpression = ((TextBox)sender).GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
if (bindingExpression != null)
{
    bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
}
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks for answers and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`, this should update your label whenever the textbox property changes.

example:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=MyValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="label"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=MyValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="textbox" />
    </StackPanel>
```

code:

```
    public partial class EditableLabelControl : Label, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _myValue;
        public string MyValue
        {
            get { return _myValue; }
            set { _myValue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("MyValue"); }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies the property changed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="property">The info.</param>
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I added UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to all binding expressions (TextBox binding, TextBlock binding and EditableLabel binding), but it doesn't helps. The mistery of my situation is that when I try to get access from code to binding property it finally calls property Setter. But it doesn't calls setter when I change property from UI :(.

Comment: does `EditableLabelControl` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: EditableLabelControl extends Label control. So it has Content property (DependencyProperty Content).

Comment: MyValue - is model's Dependency Property too

Comment: When I change text in textbox it correctly changes EditableLabel's Content Property because changes in textbox correctly updates textblock Text property (textblock is binded to same Content property). But the datamodel doesn't update :(. DataContext is valid, because when I run my application EditableLabel correctly shows datamodel value. MyValue - is dependency property in my datamodel.

Comment: Sorry, its a bit hard to see what the problem is without seeing how your Model is attached to the EditableLabel and how everything fits together

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21558/discussion-between-dmitriy-and-sa-ddam213)

Comment: The problem was in model object. I replace dependency properties with INotifyPropertyChanged properties and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: Awesome :), Sometimes it feels like dependency properties have a mind of thier own, LOL